# Multiple file inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, multiple-instances, input-field

I'm new to all of this and still learning mostly on this site, its very usefull for me, and decided to get some help from you guys.

I styled my file input button and got the file name printed inside of text field. Now I would love to use those classes on multiple file inputs (together with text field which contains file name) on the same page. (I need more file inputs, not more files at once)

I know I can use ID's and just duplicate JS for every file field that I need, but I would like to do it in one function or make it more "dynamical" for mass usage.

So, I'm asking for a little help :)

HTML:

```
<div class="upload button left">
    <input class="upbtn" type="file" name="attachment" />Add attachment
</div>
<input class="filename" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
    $(".upbtn").change(function(e) {
        var datoteka = $(this).val();
        var lastIndex = datoteka.lastIndexOf("\\");
        if (lastIndex >= 0) {
            datoteka = datoteka.substring(lastIndex + 1);
        }
        $(".filename").val(datoteka);
    });
```

You can look at whole thing here: http://jsfiddle.net/k5cLt/5/

Thx in advance

Comment: The problem is what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. I used

```
   $(".upbtn").change(function(e) {
        var datoteka = $(this).val();
        var lastIndex = datoteka.lastIndexOf("\\");
        if (lastIndex >= 0) 
        {
            datoteka = datoteka.substring(lastIndex + 1);
        }
        var close = $(this).parent().next(".filename:first")
        close.val(datoteka);
   });
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k5cLt/10/)

The alignment of your inputs and such might not be as desired, but the JSFiddle shows the general idea of what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what i was trying to achieve. Thank you very much.

Comment: and for alignment of inputs and style, i wanted to style file input with css but it didn't go quite well so this is just experiment and i know that it's not best solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try it with multiple file-fields ?
What you did should work as is.

```
$(".upbtn").change(...);
```

gives back an array of jquery-wrapped objects with the class .upbtn and calls .change() on all of them..

Comment: yes i tried to use more fields and when i click on (for example) second button and select picture, it populates both text fields. But MikeB solved my problem. thx